# What does it mean "to karma the knife"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

There's this music "Karma the knife" from Angelica Garcia. She says in chorus "I can Karma the knife", what does it mean?

In the videoclip she's like cutting a miniature of her and multiplying as cuts, but I'm not sure if it's really related to the expression meaning.

And, "karma" I understand as something like "guilty", so will she do something bad and the karma will not be hers, will be from her weapon, the knife? XD

Comment: Questions about song lyric interpretation are off topic here, although it's not always clear what is a more general language issue and what is specific to a song. If you read the lyrics, the chorus starts "I call karma 'The Knife'", and then repeats the last 3 words. Karma is not being used as a verb: the meaning is similar to if she said "Karma is like a knife" or "Karma is a knife". You could look up karma in Wikipedia or another reference work to find what it means.

Comment: You need to look up the meaning of "karma". "Guilt" is a very bad synonym.

Comment: [Corrections for The Student: How to ask a question. We write: What does "to karma the knife" mean. //She is carving a miniature of herself? Is that what you mean?]

Answer (score 1):

According to the lyrics ,
[[  I call karma "The Knife"  //
Karma the knife  //
Oh yeah, oh yeah, oh yeah  //
Karma the knife  ]] , she is giving a Name or Description to Karma; Similar to "Conan the Barbarian" or "Richard the Lionheart" ....

She is trying to claim that Karma is like a knife.

The Song is about Karma, the knife.

Here, there is no action or verb like "to sharpen/use/break/mold/point the knife", it is only a Name or Description.